# Issues deploying MVC5 web app to remote server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment, iis-8

I have a web app that runs just fine on my local machine.
It was an MVC 3 web app that I just recently moved to MVC 5
Now when I deployed it to the remove VPS, I get this error.

System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0 should not be used anywhere.
**Why am I getting this error?**

All config files should be using 3.0.0.0
The target fremework is 4.5. ASP.NET 4.5 installed on the VPS
I haven't installed MVC5 on the remote VPS.

**Are there any documentation on staps to follow to deploy MVC 5 to remote server?**

3960

w3wp.exe

IIS APPPOOL\Mysite

InvalidOperationException

The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly '**System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040). at

System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) Could not load file or assembly '**System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()

Answer (score 1):

Add an assembly binding redirect in the web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```